# Why does python gzip raise closed file error?

Tags: python, gzip

I have a file that I want to unzip. It is stored in a variable.

Code:

```
print(bytes_db)

with gzip.open(bytes_db, 'rb') as db:
    print(db)
    db.read()
```

The result is and error on a closed file. Full output:

```
<gzip on 0x7f2737f23250>
<gzip gzip on 0x7f2737f23250 0x7f273c5e3430>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: What is `bytes_db`?

Comment: It should be a database file pulled from my organizations cloud storage. Our API was used to fetch it. This is the only case of fetching a gzip file from our storage that I know of.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have wrong indentation and you run `db.read()` outside `with ... as db:` - so you run `db.read()` after closing file because `with ... as ...` automatically closes file when you use different indentation.

Comment: it seems `bytes_db` is already `gzip` file and I don't understand why you use again `gzip.open()` on this file. Maybe you should directly do `bytes_db.read()`

Comment: PeterWood and @furas have the right of it. Apparently I executed some jupyter cells out of order and wasn't really paying attention to what I was printing. Thanks all.